# Textview Paint Controls/Methods

Tags: java, android, textview, paint

I have a long string which I am trying to calculate the properly for page by page use. To achieve this I plan to use paint.breakpoint(). However I am lacking the idea calculate the string line width for `position = position+ paint.breakText(theString.substring(position), true, screenWidth, null);` where null is the length of width of the current line. I found the resource or information on [Andoid/Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html)

If someone wants to see what I have done please don't hesitate to ask.

What I want is to be able to find the null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paint.breakText(theString.substring(position), true, screenWidth, null);

This is question is a mistake since null returns something irrelevant for finding the length of a dislay line and there is no need for it.